# Ubuntu 15.10 hangs on "Starting light display manager" on bootup

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

I recently updated to 15.10, and now when I boot up, It gets stuck on 
"Starting light display manager" part of the boot sequence.

I've purged and installed xorg, lightdm, nvidia drivers, all about a hundred times. I've also looked everywhere online looking for solutions, but no success.

I have an Nvidia GeForce 750 card, and I've tried installing almost all the drivers from either their site or from aptitude.

How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: lightdn.log and x-0-greeter.log could help the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with an AMD card. I've found a work around by going into the console with

> ctrl alt f1
>
> sudo apt-get install xinit

then using the command

> startx unity

I found a solution to the problem here [Ubuntu 15.10 boot hangs when starting Lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692577/ubuntu-15-10-boot-hangs-when-starting-lightdm)

Answer (score 0):

Sound support was disabled in the BIOS of the machine for me. Hence, no driver worked. This happened because I loaded the failsafe settings in the bios while trying to get the machine to boot via floppy, CD and USB. However, once I loaded the optimized defaults in the BIOS settings, everything worked fine.